# Fixed width and height of header,footer and content in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mobile

i am learning jquerymobile with asp.net.I tried all tips for fixed header,footer
and content including the option with fixed.Still i am not getting fixed header and footer
with height.Pls help me with complete code.

with regards,
D.Vasanth